# acid alpha glucosidase vs glycogen phosphorylase

Tags: biochemistry

What’s the difference between acid alpha glucosidase and glycogen phosphorylase? Both break down the same bonds in glycogen so I thought for a long time that they are exact same enzyme until I struggled through glycogen storage disease types and found out that each one is different than the other and that deficiency of either one causes a different type of GSD.

Answer (score 1):

Acid alpha glucosidase  (sometimes called α-1,4-glucosidase or acid maltase) is not among those enzymes involved the pathways of glycogen synthesis and breakdown. It however occurs in lysosomes,where it functions to **hydrolyze** the disaccharide maltose  and linear oligosaccharides, as well as the outer branches of glycogen,thereby yielding free glucose.

This "second pathway" of glycogen metabolism is not quantitatively important as it concerns a minor fraction of glycogen. The reason that lysosomes normally take up and degrade glycogen granules is unknown perhaps for the disposal of structurally aberrant glycogen molecules.

---

Glycogen phosphorylase (a dimeric enzyme)
catalyzes glycogen **phosphorolysis** (bond cleavage by the
substitution of a phosphate group) to yield glucose-1-
phosphate (G1P).

$\ce{Glycogen + Pi <=>  glycogen + G1P}$

This enzyme will only release a glucose unit that is at least
five units from a branch point. (*Note: I am not going to describe the reaction mechanism of glycogen phosphorylase here is much more complex than it sounds*)

Having briefly described the enzymes, the most important thing to note is that:

- structually these two enzymes are different,
- active in the different locations
- the mechanism of glycogen breakdown are different (i.e phosphorylation, hydrolysis)
- different regulation mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

Both work on alfa 1~4 linkage but....
Phosphorylase for glycogen breakdown in muscles and liver 
But 1-4 glucosidase for glycogen break down in cells of other organs especially in lysosoes which inturn help cells to git rid off xss materials like glycogen.